# Basic properties of Fourier Series.9.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

let *f(x)* be the characteristic function of the interval [a,b] $\subset$ $[-\pi , \pi ]$, show that the Fourier series of $f$ is given by $$ \frac{b-a}{2\pi} + \sum_ {n \neq 0} \frac{e^{-ina} - e^{-inb}}{2\pi i n} e^{inx} $$
[The Formula for the Fourier series of the Characteristic function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf5F5.png)

I have calculated $\hat{f}(0)$ and it was $\frac{b-a}{2\pi}$ as required.  and I have calculated $\hat{f}(n)$ and it was equal to $$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2in\pi} (e^{-ina} - e^{-inb})$$.

So I solved letter(a) of  the question it was so easy, thank u very much for anyone helped me.
But the remaining part of the question is as follows:

(b)Show that if $a \ne -\pi$ or $b \ne \pi$ and $a\ne b$ then the Fourier Series does not converge absolutely to for any x.

There is a hint in the book for proving this part, but even the application for the hint is not clear for me.

The Hint is:[It suffices to prove that for many values of n one has $|sin n\theta_0| \ge c > 0$ where $\theta_0 = \frac{(b-a)}{2}$]

Could anyone help me?

Comment: The link is broken. Please format the problem and repost it. Also, you should show what you have tried.

Comment: the link open with me ......but okay I will try to send the question in an obvious way thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Fourier series of a function with period $2 \pi$ can be given by

$$f(\theta) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n cos(n \theta)+b_n sin(n \theta))$$

Where $$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta) cos n\theta d\theta$$ and 
$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta) sin n\theta d\theta$$.

You may also express the fourier series as:

$$f(\theta) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{i n \theta}$$ where

$$c_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta) e^{-i n \theta} d \theta$$

Can you, with this information and using $f(\theta)$ as the characteristic function, prove whate they are asking?

Comment: yes I`ll do and if I have problems I will ask u if u do not mind, thanks.